# how to get the TextMeshPro component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class ClickBub : MonoBehaviour {
int x;
int count;
TextMeshPro mytext;
TextMeshPro soretext;
GameObject textobj;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    textobj = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
    mytext = textobj.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
```

in this mytext is a null value. how can i assign the TextMeshValue to the variable?

also says that unity engine can't convert type.

Answer (score 11):

Well, the thing is that the **Text** for **TextMeshPro** isn't a **TextMeshPro** Object, but rather a **TMP_Text**, So if you tried this :

```
TMP_Text mytext;
void Start () {
    mytext = textobj.GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
}
```

Now you should get a value in your **mytext** object.

Comment: I realized that **TextMeshPro** is in fact a type that references the 3D text of TMP without using a UI.Canvas. Here is a [link for extra details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74794832/18791446).

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
textobj.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
```

Unity will look for the `TextMeshPro` component in the object `textobj`.
According to your code, `textobj` is the first child of the object that has the `ClickBub` script. You should first check that this first child has a TextMeshPro component in your editor. To be sure that you access the elements you expect, you can try to print their names:

```
void Start () 
{
    textobj = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
    Debug.Log(textobj.name);
}
```

Is it the object you expected?

Then if everything is setup properly but you want to **add** the TextMeshPro component if it doesn't have it, you can do

```
void Start () 
{
    textobj = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
    mytext = textobj.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    if(mytext == null)
    {
        mytext = textobj.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Very much for your reply but unfortunately ,                                                                        
void OnMouseDown(){
 
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   
   if (mytext.Equals(animals[i])) {
    
    Debug.Log ("Win");
    
   }
   else{
    Debug.Log("Lost");
   } It is still generating only lost in console please help me

Comment: Assuming `animals` contains strings, I suppose that you don't compare things that can be compared. if `mytext` is a TextMeshPro, it is not certain you can compare it to a string. Try to `Debug.Log(myText + ", " + animals[i]);` to check what values are compared. Then it is a different question, so if you need more help you could accept this answer and create a new question with your new problem