# What is the difference between TMP_Text and TextMeshProUGUI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

While making a game with Unity, I was curious about the difference between TMP_Text and TextMeshProUGUI in TMPro. Please let me know what is different from each other. I'd appreciate an example of when to use it.

I don't know why TMP_Text and TextMeshProUGUI are separated and used separately in Unity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`TMP_Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TMP_Text.html) is the base/parent class for **two** types

- [`TextMeshProUGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI.html) - replacing the now legacy [`UI.Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html) within a `UI.Canvas`
- [`TextMeshPro`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TextMeshPro.html) - replacing the now legacy [`TextMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html) for placing 3D text without using a `UI.Canvas`

  This second one is where the name of the entire package originally comes from. It was a custom improved `TextMesh` until Unity adopted it into the core.

So if you want to be more generic (loosely coupled) and make your component work in theory with whatever will be used for displaying that text later you use `TMP_Text` so both can be used the same way.

Answer (score 0):

textmeshproGUI is for UI elements when making tools for unity packages,
textmeshpro is for elements in the scene.
at least thats my understanding of it